# RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function

Tags: python, tensorflow, runtime-error

I use `tf.data.datset` API and use residual network. When I run code for TensorBoard for visualizing my embeddings I have this error, but when I use a two layers network I don't have this problem.

```
def load_and_preprocess_from_path_label(path, label):
    return load_and_preprocess_image(path), label

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((all_image_paths, all_image_labels))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # TODO (@omoindrot): remove the hard-coded 10000
    # Obtain the test labels
    image_label_ds = ds.map(load_and_preprocess_from_path_label)
    ds = image_label_ds.shuffle(image_count)
```

---

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-ead5d6a54baa> in <module>()
     92         # TODO (@omoindrot): remove the hard-coded 10000
     93         # Obtain the test labels
---> 94         image_label_ds = ds.map(load_and_preprocess_from_path_label)
     95         ds = image_label_ds.shuffle(image_count)
     96 
RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

Comment: I faced the same error while experimenting with disabling eager mode of TF2.0 by calling `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.disable_eager_mode`. The error is gone if I don't touch this function and stay eager at the toplevel. Note that Keras seems to have a different notion of eagerness (`dynamic` parameter of Model) which is _disabled_ by default.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this ?

Comment: I get this error: `ValueError: Your model contains layers that can only be successfully run in eager execution (layers constructed with dynamic=True). You must enable eager execution with tf.enable_eager_execution().` I have a quantum layer made with pennylane with `QuantumConv = qml.qnn.KerasLayer(circuit, params_shape, output_dim=n_qubits)`. Then I need to use `tf.concat` to concatenate all the TF Tensors it ouputs from the convolution. Is the problem the `tf.concat` or this layer? How should I avoid layers with eager execution?

Answer (score 4):

The error is possibly due to Tensorflow version

Running the following code  worked for me:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

## Correct function:

```
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Comment: Note that this will disable much functionality, not only the eager execution. It would be good to know what to do in tf2.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following code worked for me:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf


tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
```

It would be great if you use the following code as well to force LSTM clear the model parameters and Graph after creating the models.

```
K.clear_session()
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
#tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Comment: tf.enable_eager_execution must be called at program startup. Where do I call this?

Comment: I get this error: `ValueError: Your model contains layers that can only be successfully run in eager execution (layers constructed with dynamic=True). You must enable eager execution with tf.enable_eager_execution().` I have a quantum layer made with pennylane with `QuantumConv = qml.qnn.KerasLayer(circuit, params_shape, output_dim=n_qubits)`. Then I need to use `tf.concat` to concatenate all the TF Tensors it ouputs from the convolution. Is the problem the `tf.concat` or this layer? How should I avoid layers with eager execution?